# Object of type 'NoneType' has no len() in merge sort

Tags: python, typeerror, mergesort

I'm implementing an usual merge sort algorithm in python as follows but got an unexpected type error.

```
from typing import List

def merge(arr1: List[int], arr2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    sorted_arr = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2):
        if arr1[i] < arr2[j]:
            sorted_arr.append(arr1[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            sorted_arr.append(arr2[j])
            j = j + 1
    sorted_arr += arr1[i:]
    sorted_arr += arr2[j:]

def merge_sort(arr: List[int]):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    left_arr = merge_sort(arr[:mid])
    right_arr = merge_sort(arr[mid:])
    return merge(left_arr, right_arr)
```

The error says this:

```
while i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I have no idea why the type error can occur on the `while` loop. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: `if len(arr) == 1:` should be `if len(arr) <= 1:` to allow for empty lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't explicitly returned anything from the `merge()` method and by default it returns `None` if nothing is returned explicitly.

Return the `sorted_arr` at the end of the `merge()` method as:

```
def merge(arr1: List[int], arr2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    sorted_arr = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2):
        if arr1[i] < arr2[j]:
            sorted_arr.append(arr1[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            sorted_arr.append(arr2[j])
            j = j + 1
    sorted_arr += arr1[i:]
    sorted_arr += arr2[j:]
    return sorted_arr  # return the sorted_arr
```

Comment: Oh god thank you so much. I accidentally deleted that return statement during testing. Thanks a lot!